# Using counter to count one index in a string for Python

Tags: counter

Now, I imported Counter and I saw that it counts all the letters in the string but I would want it to only count one letter and ignore the others.. Is that possible?

run = 'Mississippi'
count = 0
for letter_s in run:
    if letter_s == 's':
        count = count + 1
    print count

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing should be totally possible.  You can iterate over most things in python and the way you're doing it should work.  I reformatted yours a bit and it works just fine.

```
run = 'Mississippi'
count = 0
for letter_s in run:
    if letter_s == 's':
        count += 1

print count
```

output is **4**

Comment: How would I make it so that I have a string statement displaying the output as 4. I'm performing this in the command prompt so I don't know if that will have any sort of effect on the way my output is displayed.. I'm also very new lol @tizzy

Comment: Oh wait I see, you printed it outside the block instead of inside. Yes this works, thank you!